# How to condense a struct in a class c++?

Tags: c++

I have a `a.h` which has a class `d`. I am wondering how to make a shorthand way to use the struct 'a' inside of my class.

```
//a.h
class d
{
    public:
    struct a
    {
      int val;
    }
};


//a.cpp
#include "a.h"
using d::a;         //line with error
a methodName()
{
  //does stuff
  return object_of_type_a;
}
```

Comment: `using d::a` doesn't work, since `d` is a `class`, not a namespace (or scoped `enum` from C++11).     Use `using a = d::a` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this one

```
class d
{
public:
    struct a
    {
        int val;
    };
};

typedef struct d::a da;
```

Comment: Or `using a = d::a;`, which I find a little easier to read than the `typedef` version.

Comment: yes,less typing is better

Comment: thanks a ton, i'm a little new to c++ syntax